# ESP8266 stops working when I use 2x static const char(PROGMEM)

Tags: esp8266, c++

*Sdk version: 2.2.2-dev(5ab15d1)
*Core Version: 2_6_1

This is the error returned:

```
Exception 3: LoadStoreError: Processor internal physical address or data error during load or store PC: 0x4000bf64 EXCVADDR: 0x4024e963
Decoding stack results 
0x4020175d: HTML1(String) at C:\Users\b.yuzo\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.6.1\cores\esp8266/WString.h line 128 
0x40238c26: umm_info(void*, int) at C:\Users\b.yuzo\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.6.1\cores\esp8266\umm_malloc/umm_info.c line 164 
0x40100278: millis() at C:\Users\b.yuzo\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.6.1\cores\esp8266\core_esp8266_wiring.cpp line 188 
0x40238c26: umm_info(void*, int) at C:\Users\b.yuzo\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.6.1\cores\esp8266\umm_malloc/umm_info.c line 164 
0x4020af74: String::copy(char const*, unsigned int) at C:\Users\b.yuzo\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.6.1\cores\esp8266\WString.cpp line 214 
0x40201a3c:
```

Code:

```
static const char HTML1[] PROGMEM = R"=====(
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head>
<meta charset='utf-8' name='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=0'>
)=====";

static const char HTML2[] PROGMEM = R"=====(
<button type='button' onclick='sendData(2)'>Test2</button>
)=====";

String html_return = HTML1;
html_return += "<button type='button' onclick='sendData(1)'>Test</button>";
Serial.println("Before Second Const Char");
html_return += HTML2; //<< ESP stops working here
```

Comment: If I remove `static` declaration, it doesn't compile in local function. I've tried to declare HTML1[] and HTML2[] out of the function without `static` declaration, but the error is the same.

Comment: I still have memory, I'm only using (42%) of 81Kbytes.
So I'm working without PROGMEM and it works like bellow:
`String HTML2 = R"=====(
<button type='button' onclick='sendData(2)'>Test2</button>
)=====";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Guide to PROGMEM on ESP8266 and Arduino IDE](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/PROGMEM.html#functions-to-read-back-from-progmem).

Since you put your char array into `PROGMEM`, special functions must be used to load it from flash into RAM; so to load it into a `String` object, the `FlashHelper` class must be used. You can simply use the macro `FPSTR(progmem_ptr)`.

```
#include <Arduino.h>

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println("\nStart firmware");

    static const char HTML1[] PROGMEM = R"=====(
    <!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' name='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=0'>
    )=====";

    static const char HTML2[] PROGMEM = R"=====(
    <button type='button' onclick='sendData(2)'>Test2</button>
    )=====";

    String html_return = HTML1;
    html_return += "<button type='button' onclick='sendData(1)'>Test</button>";
    Serial.println("Before Second Const Char");
    //html_return += HTML2; //crashes
    html_return += FPSTR(HTML2); //works
    Serial.println("Result");
    Serial.println(html_return);
}

void loop() {

}
```

Outputs

```
Start firmware
Before Second Const Char
Result

        <!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' name='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=0'>
        <button type='button' onclick='sendData(1)'>Test</button>
        <button type='button' onclick='sendData(2)'>Test2</button>
```

Comment: `FPSTR` macro casts the type and so forces the use of the right `+` operator for a PROGMEM string. It is the same as `html_return += F("some text stored in progmem");`

Comment: Dear Maximilian, thank you for the detailed answer, works very well. Saved my ESP memory!